# Maintain two tomcat installations with apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, tomcat

On our server we have two tomcat8 installations on debian wheezy. One tomcat was installed via `apt-get install` , the second instance was then just copied from the first installation. But this makes it complicated to maintain. I only get automatic updates (`apt-get update, apt-get upgrade`) for the first installation, the second installation needs to be updates manually.

Is there a way to install and update two installtions of tomcat via apt-get?

Comment: Can you explain the context a little more. Tomcat is a server, right? Why do you need two of them on one machine?

Comment: The setup with 2 tomcats is required by the applications we run on it, no chance to change it in short term.

Comment: Ok, but some more details might he helpful. Do some apps use one server and some apps the other server? Do the servers need to be exactly the same version?

Comment: yes some apps are deployed in server one and other ones in server2. Both tomcat servers should have the same version.

Comment: Ok, if you want to independent versions both installed from upstream and which will be maintained by upstream, I think installing one in a chroot and making it available to the main system might be an option. The chroot can probably be set up to be updateable via apt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't copy the files. You can run multiple copies of the same executable.

If you really need to have tomcat installed in another directory hierarchy, make [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). You can use a script like this:

```
dpkg -L tomcat6 tomcat6-common |
while IFS= read -r x; do
  if ! [ -d "$x" ]; then
    mkdir -p "/srv/alt-tomcat/${x%/*}"
    ln -s "$x" "/srv/alt-tomcat/$x"
  fi
done
```

You'll still need to update the symbolic links when the list of files contained in the package changes, but not for security updates and other bug fixes.

Comment: Would two servers run OK independently in that kind of setup? What about them running on the same ports, because presumably the config would be identical too?

Comment: @FaheemMitha You would of course run the two servers with different configuration files. But unless there's something really weird about tomcat (which I can't completely rule out), you wouldn't duplicate any of the files from the distribution, only the configuration file which you'd modify anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, I will try it out in our demo environment and let you know.